# jsf template layout includes forms

Tags: templates, jsf-2

I have written a template page for using in every page.In this template includes a left div a haed div and a footer.So central is for my forms.But forms are viewing below of footer.How to solve this layout problem.Here is my using of template

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Hakkında</title>
</h:head>
<body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/mainTemplate.xhtml">
        <h:form>
            Some components
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in template space for body

```
<ui:insert name="body">Default Body</ui:insert>
```

and redefine it in your view (page)

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="homeForm">
        <!-- your components -->
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now my left menu that in template is sliding down when I add component into the body.I have used          <ui:composition template="/templates/mainTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="body">
                <h:form id="homeForm">
   someComponents
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

Comment: So I want to align two div in my template